# html2pdf : text-align: justify does not work

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, html2pdf

Here my problem, I'm using `html2pdf` in `php` in order to generate a letter. All is working, apart for one thing : I am not able to achieve justify a paragraph in my pdf.

here a sample of my content

```
$content .= "<p style='padding-left: 94.4882px; padding-right: 94.4882px; top: 275.333px; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at velit dignissim, sollicitudin erat a, pretium turpis. Suspendisse placerat, mauris nec porta ultricies, lectus diam aliquam nulla, eu tristique mauris elit a eros. Aenean semper vestibulum elit, non ullamcorper orci mattis sed. Nullam tempor facilisis nibh, at accumsan ipsum pharetra id. Cras ultricies eget est et blandit. Duis quam tellus, posuere at quam sit amet, posuere euismod velit. Sed vel tellus vel tortor lacinia aliquet. Etiam sed urna ut mi tincidunt mattis ac non justo. In eu est eget est tristique auctor nec vel enim. Etiam non finibus turpis. Suspendisse potenti.
                </p><br/>";
```

I'm using html2pdf v 4.03 ; as far as the internet can tell, it seems it can be usually handled by css property. I am trying to change my `<p>` into a `<div>`, or using html property `align="justify"` but nothing works. My code even work correctly in strict html (I ran a test with a page test.html) !

Any idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: Try to set width:100% of `<p>`

Comment: nope, ain't working either. I have the feeling that it work on the first line, but not on the others ???

Comment: can you please put more of you code to let me understand what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Justify doesn't work perfectly for me even in html2pdf v4.6.0. I'd file a bug report. In the meantime you might look up an alternative library like TCPDF, which has a `WriteHTML()` method.

Comment: There's not really much code I can add, all the html still work there juste this justify that will not be shown on pdf. The vexing part is that it work on nav with standard html. I think I'll try Matt method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the "94.4882px" is a good idea. 
Try with "94px" or better, in mm "94mm" or adapt it to your letter.

And always put ' ' for your text, because PHP will try to find variable in the text for nothing ( just lost time) ;)

```
$content .= '<p style="padding-left: 94px; padding-right: 94px; top: 275px; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at velit dignissim, sollicitudin erat a, pretium turpis. Suspendisse placerat, mauris nec porta ultricies, lectus diam aliquam nulla, eu tristique mauris elit a eros. Aenean semper vestibulum elit, non ullamcorper orci mattis sed. Nullam tempor facilisis nibh, at accumsan ipsum pharetra id. Cras ultricies eget est et blandit. Duis quam tellus, posuere at quam sit amet, posuere euismod velit. Sed vel tellus vel tortor lacinia aliquet. Etiam sed urna ut mi tincidunt mattis ac non justo. In eu est eget est tristique auctor nec vel enim. Etiam non finibus turpis. Suspendisse potenti.</p><br/>';
```